# How did Lucy go from being a mule to being chained in a prison cell?

Tags: plot-explanation, lucy

In the movie Lucy (2014), the main character gets drugs sewn into her body, given an airplane ticket and then lectured by some Taiwanese gangsters about how she has 24 hours to fly to Europe to deliver the drugs.

In a huge non-sequitur, the very next scene shows her chained in a medieval-esque prison cell with would-be rapists.

What happened? I assume scenes that would have explained what happened were cut out of the movie.

Comment: Wasn't she just still in captivity by the gangsters, waiting for plane boarding time?

Comment: To Kitkat
The original mobsters were (South) Korean, but her "jailers" were Chinese. The plot still needs some clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The [film script](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/lucy-2014.pdf) is, perhaps, a little clearer than the film itself.

Lucy is hooded in scene 11 and told that her flight will be ***in the next day or so***.

> A Chinese gangster hands out passports and plane tickets.
>
> **THE LIMEY** (typically British politeness): *Good morning to you, gentlemen and lady. First of all, many thanks for
> taking part in this experiment, which I'm sure will go off
> flawlessly. These passports and tickets will enable you to return
> home within the next twenty-four hours. Upon arrival, you will be
> taken in hand by our people, so that we might recover our merchandise
> and you might rediscover the freedom you so richly deserve. But enough of my speedy lying. Gentlemen, lady... allow me to wish you "bon voyage!"*
>
> **The guards rush over and pull hoods over the guinea pigs' heads.**

She's then taken somewhere in a car. This turns out to be a warehouse close to the city where she will await her flight.

> **BLACKOUT.**
> We hear Lucy's breathing. Hard and fast. Like her heartbeat.
> Fear in her belly.
> Gradually, we sense a little more light.
> **The sound of an engine. The city.**
> Through the thick weave of the hood into Lucy's private sphere.
> Her eye. Her mouth. Mumbling to herself. [snip]
>
> **INT. ROOM**
>
> Suddenly, **the hood is ripped off. Bright, dazzling light.**
> Straight into poor Lucy's face.